# How Do I Fix Unmet dependencies Linux-Image-Generic etc

Tags: dependencies

My battery died on an upgrade and now I have this problem when I try to install updates. How do I fix it?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-generic: Depends: linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.52.62) but 3.2.0.57.68 is installed
Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.52.62) but 3.2.0.57.68 is installed
```

Comment: Hi

It is not working. I am seeing things along the lines of:

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux generic:

and 

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):

dependency problems leaving unconfigured

Answer (score 16):

Fire this at command line:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install -f
```

This checks your lib and if it finds unmet dependency, it'll fetch the needed files and install them.

Meanwhile - that dependency version of image-generic told me that you are running on 12.04.  Perhaps this case will do the trick:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install syslinux-themes-debian-wheezy
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
    $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

Comment: Hi It is not working. I am seeing things along the lines of: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux generic: and dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure): dependency problems leaving unconfigured –

Comment: see my edit to reflect options

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this unmet dependencies problem while trying to do an "apt-get upgrade", but also had the additional issue of /boot having run out of space.

Some errors which provide clues that your /boot is out of space:

> gzip: stdout: No space left on device
>
> No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error

This meant that apt-get was helpless, with "sudo apt-get install -f" and "sudo apt-get autoremove" failing to work.

In the end, the link in Justin's answer provided the solution:

1) Check how many old linux-generic kernels you've got installed:

```
find /boot -type f -regex "^.*-generic"
```

2) If more than 2, manually clean out the old ones

```
sudo find /boot -type f -regex "^.*XX-generic" -delete
```

Replacing *XX* with the number of the old kernel you wish to remove (e.g. find /boot -type f -regex "^.*24-generic" -delete) **Make sure you leave the latest two kernels (highest two numbers).**

3) Now you've got space to fix the unmet dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 5):

Removing and reinstalling `linux-generic` will solve this issue.To do this,try the below command on virtual console(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-generic    
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic
```

Comment: Isn't it a tad bit dangerous to purge `linux-generic`?! Wouldn't that remove the kernel? So if you reboot in the middle of it... bye bye everything?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/261256) answers your question

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a fairly old thread, but found a solution on another forum. 
The person suggested deleting all of the old kernel files as I ran into the same problem. It was because my /boot partition was full and therefore apt couldn't unpack and install anything.
Here it is:
[How to handle out of space errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134897/how-to-handle-out-of-space-errors)

Cheers, 
Justin

Comment: Hah! I know of that one, but rarely think about looking are my `df /boot`... I had to run `apt-get autoremove --purge` once to get things back in order (i.e. the following `dist-upgrade` still generated an error, but after that, all good!)